# MVC - Looking for a better way to get from URL to view

Tags: php, model-view-controller

The below example shows how I am currently doing things.

index.php includes index_controller.php then index_template.php.

**index_controller.php**

```php
$uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$action = $uri[1];
$call = $uri[2];

$tmp = explode('?', $call);
$call = $tmp[0];

$call = preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $call);

switch ($action) {
    case "about":
        $page = "about.inc.php";
        $title = "About Us";
        $description = "Description of page";
        break;
    case "category":
        try {
            //PDO query to make sure category ($call) exists
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            logError($e->getMessage());
        }
        if (query->rowCount() < 1) {
            $page = "404.inc.php";
            $title = "404 Error";
        }
        else {
            //Meta information for selected category pulled from DB and put into variables.
            $page = "category.inc.php";
        break;
    default:
        $page = "404.inc.php";
        $title = "404 Error";
}
```

The above example shows 2 of around 12 different page options in the switch statement.  A simple request (about) and a more complex request (category).

`index_template.php` has all my head, body, and footer HTML.  It sets the meta data for the page, sets up the sites structure, and includes whatever file the `$page` variable is set to in `index_controller.php`

Using the above example, if someone goes to **mysite.com/category/books** `index_controller.php` will see if the books category exists and if it does `category.inc.php` will be included.

`category.inc.php` does another PDO query to get all the items and information required to display a list of items for the selected category.  It also includes a template file to structure the display of the returned items.

I am trying to achieve a MVC type structure (without using a framework like Codeigniter or CakePHP), but I don't really have the model end down.

How can I get the user from the URL to the view using classes and/or functions instead of all the includes I am currently using?

If you feel I didn't do a good job explaining the other files mentioned I can provide code examples from those files as well.

Any help, input, or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Clarified question as per comment below.

Comment: This is quite a broad question - it almost reads as "how can I build an MVC framework?" The title of the question hints at something a bit more specific, but you never really clarify that. If you haven't already, take a look at the [help], as it's important to understand how this site is different from a normal forum: you're not starting a conversation, so you need to focus on a particular question, and make sure it's "on topic" for the site.

Comment: @IMSoP Sorry for the broad question.  I edited it to try to clarify the actual question.  Hope this helps to give a better understanding as to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

With a little trick and with `.htaccess` you can make this much easier.

I use this method in my self made MVC based application. You can copy paste the whole code or just use a part of it. The main logic is in the Bootstrap class.

.htaccess

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /news [R]
```

index.php

```
require 'brInit.php';

$app = new \brInclude\brClasses\mvc\Bootstrap();
```

I use brInit to automatically include classes and to include my config file

Bootstrap.php

```
class Bootstrap {
    private $url = array();
    /** @var Controller $controller */
    private $controller;

    function __construct(){
        try {
            $this->_getUrl();

            $this->_loginUser();

            if(!$this->_setController($this->url[0]))
                throw new Exception('404');

            if(!$this->_executeControllersMethod())
                throw new Exception('404');
        } catch(Exception $e){
            $this->_error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    private function _error($msg){
        $this->url = array('Error', 'error', $msg);
        $this->_setController($this->url[0]);
        $this->_loginUser();
        $this->_executeControllersMethod();
    }

    private function _getUrl(){
        if(isset($_GET['url']))
            $this->url = explode('/', rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'));
        else
            $this->url = array('news');

        unset($_GET['url']);
    }

    private function _setController($name){
        $path = 'brInclude/brMVC/controller/';
        if(!file_exists($path)) return false;

        $url = ucfirst($name) . 'Controller';
        $namespace = str_replace('/', '\\', $path);
        $file = $path . $url . '.php';
        if(!file_exists($file)) return false;

        $classWithNamespace = $namespace . $url;
        $this->controller = new $classWithNamespace;
        $this->controller->view->name = $name;
        return true;
    }

    private function _loginUser(){
        $model = new UserModel();
        $user = $model->login();
        Controller::$user = $user;
    }

    private function _executeControllersMethod(){
        if(isset($this->url[1])){
            if(method_exists($this->controller, $this->url[1])){
                $count = count($this->url);
                if($count > 2)
                    call_user_func_array(
                        array($this->controller, $this->url[1]),
                        array_slice($this->url, 2)
                    );
                else
                    $this->controller->{$this->url[1]}();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $this->controller->index();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static function isLoginRequired(){
        return self::$loginRequired;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi :) There's a lot of code here, and not a lot of explanation (even in comments in the code). What is the "little trick"? Which part of the code do you think is particularly pertinent to the question? (I realise the question itself is quite broad...)

Comment: Hi! Sorry, my bad. So the trick here I use `.htaccess` to pass the request uri as a get parameter and then split that up in php. With this I get an array. The first item of the array declares which Controller it should include (you can set a default controller but I use `.htaccess` to redirect when nothing is set). The second item is the method if the selected Controller and all the other items are the parameters of that method.

Comment: @Nergal Thank you for your answer!  This looks much cleaner than how I am currently doing things.  Using parts of your example in my code will help get me on the path I am looking for.

Comment: @Jay Your welcome. If you need more help just leave a comment. Also if this was the answer you're looking for please accept it.